# How do I create a file at a specific path?

Tags: python

In python I´m creating a file doing:

```
f = open("test.py", "a")
```

where is the file created? How can I create a file on a specific path?

```
f = open("C:\Test.py", "a")
```

returns error.

Comment: The first edit to this question obscured the problem, I've put it back.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The file path `"c:\Test\blah"` will have a tab character for the `\T'.  You need to use either:

```
"C:\\Test"
```

or

```
r"C:\Test"
```

Comment: You can also use a slash `/` in python under windows as a path separator: `"C:/Test"`

Comment: I try to do this things but python returns me: Permission denied... thanks!!

Comment: I´am crazy!! executing this as administrator is posible!! thanks!!

Comment: Better to use `os.path.join('path', 'to', 'directory')`. You can get the root directory (`C:\ ` on windows or `/` on Unix-like systems) by calling `os.path.abspath(os.sep)`

Answer (score 26):

I recommend using the **os** module to avoid trouble in cross-platform. (*windows,linux,mac*)

Cause if the directory doesn't exists, it will return an exception.

```
import os

filepath = os.path.join('c:/your/full/path', 'filename')
if not os.path.exists('c:/your/full/path'):
    os.makedirs('c:/your/full/path')
f = open(filepath, "a")
```

If this will be a function for a system or something, you can improve it by adding try/except for error control.

Answer (score 3):

> where is the file created?

In the application's current working directory. You can use `os.getcwd` to check it, and `os.chdir` to change it.

Opening file in the root directory probably fails due to lack of privileges.

Answer (score 3):

It will be created once you close the file (with or without writing). Use `os.path.join()` to create your path eg

```
filepath = os.path.join("c:\\","test.py")
```

Comment: sorry but I don´t understand... what can I modify the path of creation?

Answer (score 1):

The file is created wherever the root of the python interpreter was started.

Eg, you start python in `/home/user/program`, then the file "test.py" would be located at `/home/user/program/test.py`

Comment: that is right... and what can I obtain from a script the path of the file in order to copy to another path?

Comment: As PiotrLegnica said, use `os.cwd` to get the current directory, which you can store to a string and use as you wish. The `os` module has a lot of nice features for file handling. [OS Module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)

Answer (score 1):

f = open("test.py", "a")   Will be created in whatever directory the python file is run from.

I'm not sure about the other error...I don't work in windows.

Answer (score 1):

The besty practice is to use '/' and a so called 'raw string' to define file path in Python.

```
path = r"C:/Test.py"
```

However, a normal program may not have the permission to write in the `C:` drive root directory. You may need to allow your program to do so, or choose something more reasonable since you probably not need to do so.

Comment: If you're using the forward slash as path separator, then you're eliminating the need for raw string.

Comment: o you don't, because file names can have \ in their names. It's silly, it's useless, but it's legal.

Answer (score 0):

Use os module

```
filename = "random.txt"

x = os.path.join("path", "filename")

with open(x, "w") as file:
    file.write("Your Text")
    file.close
```